# add a search bar to GMSPlacePicker(iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using GMSPlacePicker from google and it is looking great.But i would like to customise the view controller of the GMSPlacePicker and add a search bar at the top.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in the Places API for iOS! I'm an engineer working on this product.

In the next release of the API, we're planning to include autocomplete functionality in GMSPlacePicker, which will display place predictions based on user search input.

So you're out of luck at the moment, but hang tight until the next release and we'll have something then.

Comment: Following up on this, we've just released the new version of the SDK with autocomplete in the Place Picker. You can download the new version here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start

Answer (score 2):

Update [GoogleMaps.framework](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_1_get_the_latest_version_of_xcode) It will add search bar to the navigation bar by default.

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I was using

`appDelegate.initialViewController = self`

at the start of my first viewController. Plus I was also using a navigationController with a hidden navbar as I was using a custom navbar in my app. Commenting
 `appDelegate.initialViewController = self`

showed the nav bar but I needed that line. So the solution is to write this before presenting your GMSController

```
navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = false
```